# Saber si una variable no tiene datos

Tags: javascript

Tengo un modal al que le paso por javascript una variable, el caso es que esta variable  no tengo forma de contorlar cuando esta vacia o tiene datos. 
El paso de variable data-url  al que le asigno convenio.url_also lo hace bien, ya que desde el modal si le hago un alert y tiene datos los muestra.

Por si vale de algo, variable en origen viene de un json de un archivo php al que llamo con la funcion ajax, como el campo es texto enriquecido, para quitar los restos de html aplico esto:

```
$data->url_aso=strip_tags($data->url_aso);  //strip_tags elimina tags html de una cadena dada
    $data->url_aso=str_replace ("p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }" , "" , $data->url_aso  ); //Esto lo  hago ya que despues del strip_tags queda este resto y lo sustituyo por ""
```

Esta es la función donde le paso la variable.

```
$.each(objJsonConBus, function(f, convenio){
        conv += '<li>'+
            '<div '"data-url="'+convenio.url_aso +'  "data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" >'+
                '<div class="card"><center><img class="img-responsive " src="'+convenio.base64_png+'" />'+
                '<h5 CLASS="descuento ">'+subDescuento+'</h5></center></div></div>'+
            '</li>';
        });
```

Este es el modal que recibe la variable.

```
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {   
            var nameConv = $(e.relatedTarget).data('url'); 

              if(nameConv!="")
               {
                 alert(nameConv);
                }

    });
```

De la forma que me indicais, siempre me hace el alert. Aunque el alert me lo muestre vacio.

comprobando  con typeof, si pongo number siempre me dice que es false, si pongo undefined, tambien me dice siempre que es false, solo me dice que es true si pongo string, que me dice siempre que es string, me da la impresion que se queda algun tipo de residuo que no aparece en el alert pero javaescript no considera la variable como vacia.

Comment: Intenta comparar con tres símbolos de equidad en lugar de 2 "==="

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay varias formas de saberlo:

```js
  //si es simple
    var variable1 = null;
    if(!variable1) {
       console.log('sin valor 1');
    }
    
    //si es un objeto
    var variable2 = {};
    if(Object.keys(variable2).length < 1) {
       console.log('sin valor 2');
    }
    
    //saber si un objeto tiene un campo
    function contains(propiedad, objeto) {
       for(key in objeto) {
         if(key == propiedad) {
           return true;  
         }
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Tambíen debes tener en cuenta [los valores falsos de javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 3):

Por la forma en que incluís el data-url en el div, tenés la seguridad de que siempre va a estar declarada la propiedad url en el objeto devuelto por data por lo que lo único que tenés que hacer es chequear si esta tiene contenido o no y en el caso de los strings es como vos indicas con:

```
    if (variable != "") {
        // si tiene contenido
    } else {
        // si no tiene
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

el error esta en esta linea

```
var nameConv = $(e.relatedTarget).data().url;
```

debes usar url dentro del metodo data()

```
var nameConv = $(e.relatedTarget).data('url');
```

ahí obtienes `data-url`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes saber si el valor fue enviado con la funcion [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof)

```js
function ver(valor){
    console.log("viene el valor?" ,  (typeof(valor) !== 'undefined'))
}
ver(1)
ver()
```